# div floating over table

Tags: html

I am trying to get a div to float over a table so it will be on top of all the text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position), and possibly [z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) as well (although if this is your only absolutely-positioned content, you won't need it). Although there are other ways to get things to overlap, that's probably the most relevant for you.

Very simple example:

CSS:

```
#target {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Something before the table</p>
<div id="target">I'm on top of the table</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
      <td>Text in the table</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ojovag) | [source](http://jsbin.com/ojovag/edit)

Comment: @davenpcj: Thanks for letting me know. I'm shocked to find that I *ever* linked to that site in the first place. Updated to link to the W3C docs, and added example.

Answer (score 10):

I would wrap the table in a "positioned" div. I set the div to `position:relative` so that it won't interrupt the flow of the rest of the documents contents.

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <table style="width: 500px;">
    <tr>
      <td>Table Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 500px; background: green;">
    I am on TOP of the table!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with TJ - z-index is the way to go - using javascript and css/html will allow you to hide/show this "magic floating box" above the table.

Answer (score 0):

Float this over the text

```
<style>
   #floatme{
       position: absolute;
       top: XXpx;
       left: XXpx;
   }
</style>
```

Just change the top and left variables.

Comment: Still need `z-index` depending on where it is in the markup compared to the things it will be on top of.