# float table over a div in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a code like

```
<div id="container" >
     <div id="content"></div>                               
    <table id="link" cellspacing=0px; cellpadding=0px;>
    </table>    
</div>
```

with css

```
#contentDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#content {
    width:90%;
    height:60%;
    margin-left:20px;   
    display: inline;    
    vertical-align: left;
    z-index:40;

}
#link {
    width:30%;
    height:50%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float: right;
    z-index:70;

}
```

i want it to display like 
[image]

without absolute [div floating over table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955810/div-floating-over-table)

but its not displaying like that any help is appreciated?

Comment: Why don't you want to use absolute positioning?

Comment: wow, your css is really bad: you can't add dimensions to inline elements, z-index only works on positioned elements, vertical-align can't have a horizontal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a floating div but make the `left-margin` of the div a negative number so it 'floats' over the table

Answer (score 0):

For example:

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#content {
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    height: 60px;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;

 }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First: You have a `container` element, but no CSS statements tied to it. And you have a `contentDiv` CSS statement, but no corresponding HTML element.

Second: As davblayn mentioned, you can use a negative `margin-left` value.

```
#link {
    ...
    margin-right:-40px;
    ...
}
```

[See an example here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/YN2Ab/).

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `display` property of each table element to `block`, it will force the table back into block mode and then everything works fine.

```
<div style="float:right;background:red;width:200px;">This is a test.</div>
<table style="display:block;background:green;">
<tr style="display:block;">
<td style="display:block;">
This is a very long string. This string should break to the next line instead of spanning across like usual.
</td>
```